# How to retrieve only a single row

Tags: t-sql

Shown below is part of the view **view_ar_rate_detail**. I am trying to retrieve the 'daily_pay_rate' having 'eff_date_from' just prior to or equal to '2018-10-01'
The query shown below retrieves all rows ... I am missing something ...cant figure out what

```
fac_id  eff_date_from   daily_pay_rate
   3    1/1/2018       195.03
   3    11/1/2017      195.03
   3    9/1/2017       195.03
   3    8/1/2017       198.23
   3    2/1/2017       198.23
   3    9/1/2016       198.23
   3    9/1/2015       197.43
   3    2/1/2015       197.43


SELECT fac_id,eff_date_from,daily_pay_rate
FROM [view_ar_rate_detail] D
where fac_id = 3
and care_level = 'RAD'
and revenue_code = 100
and payer_id = 3
and rate_type_id = 2
and eff_date_from =
                 (select top 1 eff_date_from
                        [view_ar_rate_detail] 
                        where fac_id = D.Fac_id
                        and care_level = D.care_level
                        and revenue_code = D.revenue_code
                        and payer_id = D.payer_id
                        and rate_type_id = D.rate_type_id
                        and eff_date_from <= '2018-10-01'
                order by eff_date_from desc)
```

Comment: replace all the references in the correlated subquery with the actual values, i.e. D.Fac_id becomes 3.

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard. I got it to work. When working with the entire view, there were a couple of fields that had to be joined to make the query unique.

Comment: you can delete your question in that case.